# iOS Swift Segues

Tags: ios, swift, segue, navigationcontroller

What I want:
When I'm on my green screen and push the button "PushToBrown" I want the brown screen "think" that I'm coming from blue. So if push the back Button in my brown screen I always want to go back to blue.

At the moment:
I call from my green screen programmatically for example performSegueWithIdentifier(..., nil) and can switch to brown or just implement it by drag&drop (from the button "PushToBrown" to the brownVC screen). But if push the "back Button" I go back to Green.
-> How can I tell brown he should always go back to blue?

[image: Segue Example]

I suppose that's a problem with the navigation Controller. You could also help me if you know some really good tutorials for segues or navigationcontroller handlding.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for your problem would be unwind segue : [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

What you should do ( as you can see in the link ) is add exit point, create unwind method and call that one instead of simple `popViewcontroller`. The first answer contains both explanation, code examples, and both Objective-C and swift

Comment: And this will also work with the "BackButton" in the TopBar?

Comment: Sure thing, you just have to set your own event to go "back". In other words, you will have to create uibarbutton with event for unwind segue